# How do I use trigonometric functions for template functions/classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing code for scientific calculation which uses trigonometric functions, and since I need to use not only float/double but also multiprecision floating point numbers, I'm templatizing the functions and classes.

Let's say I'm simply writing a function to calculate `sin(pi*x) * cos(pi*x)`:

```
template <class Real>
Real sincos(const Real& x);
```

How can I use proper versions of trigonometric functions and pi value? Multiprecision floating point libraries usually have their own version of trigonometric functions, and `std::` versions are defined only for `float`, `double`, and `long double`, and `M_PI` is not even standard.

I tried putting function pointers as arguments, but `std::` versions are overloaded functions not template, so I should put it like `(double (*)(double)&std::sin)` which hurts readability and it's hard to use.

```
template <class Real>
Real sincos(const Real& x,
            Real (*sin)(const Real&), Real (*cos)(const Real&), const Real& pi)
{
    return sin(pi*x) * cos(pi*x);
}

// I don't think it's well designed function if it's hard to use like this.
double s = sincos<double>(0, (double (*)(double))&std::sin,
                             (double (*)(double))&std::cos,
                             M_PI);

my_mpf = sincos<my_mpf>(0, somewhere::my_sin, somewhere::my_cos, my_mpf_version_of_pi);
```

The problem is that there are lots of math functions needed, so I can not simply put those into the function parameters.

How should I generalize those calculations?

Comment: Rename your sun/cos functions or put them in another namespace so the don't collide with the std functions, if this is what you want.

Comment: Why not use overloading instead of templating? Also, the name of your function already reflects what it does, i.e. why pass pointers to `std::sin` and `std::cos` as template arguments?

Comment: @bazz-dee I'm not trying to make my own sin/cos functions. It was just an example. It's not good for example obviously, I'll make it simpler later.

Comment: @IvanP. Do you mean that I should implement all functions by hand for every type I want to use? like `sincos(float x)`, `sincos(double x)`, `sincos(long double x)`, `sincos(my_mpf x)`, `sincos(mpflib_a x)` and `sincos(mpflib_b x)`?

Comment: @kukyakya I thought you only wanted the functions for your special types, for which you will have to specialize your templates anyway, I assume. In any case, why not only template the variable type, and leave the function pointers out of template arguments? If you want to use custom `sin` and `cos` for your special types, then specialize the templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider going the [`char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) route.

```
// default implementation calls std::<stuff>
template<class T>
struct trig_traits {
    static constexpr T pi() { return T(3.14159265359); }
    static auto sin(T v) { return std::sin(v); }
    static auto cos(T v) { return std::cos(v); }
    // etc.
};
```

You can then specialize `trig_traits<my_mpf>` as needed. Your actual function template will then look like

```
template <class Real>
Real sincos(const Real& x) {
    using traits = trig_traits<Real>;
    return traits::sin(traits::pi() * x) * traits::cos(traits::pi() * x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Provide function overloads for the functions that return PI, sin, and cosine for different types. Use template versions whenever it's appropriate.
2. Implement `sincos` using a template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

// Generic implementation of PI().
template <class Real>
Real PI(Real const& dummy)
{
   return (Real)M_PI;
}

// Add overloads of PI for your own types.

// Generic implementation of Sine().
template <class Real>
Real Sine(Real const& x)
{
   return std::sin(x);
}

// Add overloads of Sine for your own types.

// Generic implementation of Cosine().
template <class Real>
Real Cosine(Real const& x)
{
   return std::cos(x);
}

// Add overloads of Cosine for your own types.

// Generic implementation of sincos().
template <class Real>
Real sincos(const Real& x)
{
   return Sine(PI(Real{0})*x) * Cosine(PI(Real{0})*x);
}

int main()
{
   double s1 = sincos<double>(0.2);
   float s2 = sincos<float>(0.15);

   std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << std::endl;
   std::cout << "s2: " << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
s1: 0.475528
s2: 0.404509
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will look both in `namespace std` and the argument-dependent namespace:

```
template<typename T>
T sincos(T x)
{
   using namespace std;
   return sin(x) * cos(x);
}
```

This does assume that the relevant types were implemented properly, i.e. in their own namespace with the standard names for the operators. If not you might need to do the wrapping:

```
namespace myReals
{
   using Real = ::myReal;
   using cos  = ::myRealCos;
   using sin  = ::myRealSin;
}
```

Comment: An alias with `using` can only alias types, and also doesn't affect ADL.